# MercurialEclipse rename

Tags: plugins, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I choose Mercurial as repo. The root of the project is `/Myproject` and contains folders `/MyProject/src`, and `/MyProject/res`; Now I want to add rename folders in the repository to create another hierarchy:

```
/MyProject/Server/src
/MyProject/Server/res
/MyProject/Client/a
/MyProject/Client/b
```

How can I do this in MercurialEclipse plugin, without using hg rename commands in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line that's:

```
hg rename src Server/src
hg rename red Server/res
hg commit -m 'moved res and src into Server'
```

presumably you can do that in MercurialEclipse too, but maybe it's time to toss the GUI crutches to the side.

Comment: ok @Ry4an; sorry for one more question; the following command works without problem? (i'm new on mercury, but is just fear...) hg rename src/A/B/C/*.java (rename all files without lost original names?)

Comment: That command won't work without a destination, and it will need to be a directory.  Something like `hg rename src/A/B/C/*.java dest/A/B/C` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a Refactor/Rename (Refactor->Rename from a file's context menu, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). MercurialEclipse will automatically schedule the relevant changes (removing the old file and adding the new one).